# How to use bundle transformer to Minify CSS or JS

Tags: c#, asp.net, minify

I want to use bundle transformer to bundle and minify my css collection
, but however i tried it doesn't work

heres my code, please give me some advise, thanks.

```
        var nullBuilder = new NullBuilder();
        var cssTransformer = new StyleTransformer(new CleanCssMinifier());
        var nullOrderer = new NullOrderer();

        BundleResolver.Current = new CustomBundleResolver();

        var commonStylesBundle = new Bundle("~/bundles/css/site");
        commonStylesBundle.IncludeDirectory("~/Content/sass", "*.css");

        commonStylesBundle.Builder = nullBuilder;
        commonStylesBundle.Transforms.Add(cssTransformer);
        commonStylesBundle.Orderer = nullOrderer;

        bundles.Add(commonStylesBundle);
```

it always output the html like this:

```
<link href="/Content/sass/card.css?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%2fbundles%2fcss%2fsite" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/sass/header.css?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%2fbundles%2fcss%2fsite" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/sass/login.css?bundleVirtualPath=%7e%2fbundles%2fcss%2fsite" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Comment: You running in debug? Make sure [BundleTable.EnableOptimizations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.optimization.bundletable.enableoptimizations%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is set to true.

Comment: ohh, i forgot switch this var to true, thanks.

Comment: but, is it can be switch in config file, not cs file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to set debug mode as false in the config. Or alternatively do the following in code-

```
BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
```